# jax-rs ContextResolver<T> undestanding

Tags: jakarta-ee, jax-rs, resolver

But I was trying to understand the usage of Providers in jax-rs. But was not able to understand how ContextResolver can be used. Can someone explain this with some basic example?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will see it being used a lot in resolving a serialization context object. For example an `ObjectMapper` for JSON serialization. For example

```
@Provider
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public static JacksonContextResolver implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {
    private final ObjectMapper mapper;

    public JacksonContextResolver() {
        mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> cls) {
        return mapper;
    }
}
```

Now what will happen is that the Jackson provider, namely `JacksonJsonProvider`, when serializing, will first see if it has been given an `ObjectMapper`, if not it will lookup a `ContextResolver` for the `ObjectMapper` and call `getContext(classToSerialize)` to obtain the `ObjectMapper`. So this really is an opportunity, if we wanted to do some logic using the passed `Class` to determine which mapper (if there are more than one) to use for which class. For me generally, I only use it to configure the mapper.

The idea is that you can lookup up arbitrary objects basic on some context. An example of how you would lookup the `ContextResolver` is through the [`Providers`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/ext/Providers.html#getContextResolver-java.lang.Class-javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType-) injectable interface. For example in a resource class

```
@Path("..")
public class Resource {
    @Context
    private Providers provider;

    @GET
    public String get() {
        ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> resolver
            = providers.getContextResolver(ObjectMapper.class, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        ObjectMapper mapper = resolver.getContext(...);
    }
}
```

Comment: That was nice example. isn't it can be used as factory to produce objects depending on the input.

Comment: You can read the explanation in [the spec 4.3 Context Providers](https://jsr311.java.net/nonav/releases/1.1/spec/spec.html). It doesn't go into great detail about _what_ it should be used for, so I imagine it's for general purpose use. If you can make it work, then use it I guess.

Comment: I haven't been able to find any documentation that states what type of object should be returned from a `ContextResolver` for a particular content type, but I did find this comment in the RestEasy docs: ["You should not use this feature unless you know what you're doing."](https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/4.3.1.Final/userguide/html/Built_in_JAXB_providers.html#Pluggable_JAXBContext_s_with_ContextResolvers)